# How do I fill an array with multiple api calls?

Tags: javascript, arrays, scope, spotify

I'm getting stuck trying to figure out how to fill this 'artists' array with consecutive calls to the spotify api. I'm trying to fill the 'artists' array with every artist in the user's saved library. The way the call works is, it will return a chunk of max 50 artists per call. However when I fill the array here and then try to pass a new i value to the getUserData function, I don't think the i value is updated and for some reason my 'artists' array is filling up to only 226 while the 'total' value is 276 for my test case. Can someone help me with this? I think it may be a scope issue but I can't figure out where. Thank you in advance!

```
var i = 0;
function getUserData(accessToken, i) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/tracks?limit=50&offset=' + i,
        headers: {
           'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
        }
    });
}

 var artists = [];
 loginButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      login(function(accessToken) {


       getUserData(accessToken, i)
            .then(function(response) {
            var total = response.total;

            while(i < total) {
            i+=50;
             getUserData(accessToken, i)
            .then(function(response) {
                total = response.total;
                alert(total); //testing
                loginButton.style.display = 'none';

for (var j = 0; j < 50 && artists.length < total; j++){                         

    artists.push(response.items[j].track.album.artists[0].name);
}
         alert(artists[7] + artists.length); //testing
         alert(artists[artists.length - 1]); //testing
            });
            }  


            });



        });
});
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Just a quick guess - have you tried while(i <= total) instead of while(i < total)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your first `getUserData` in the while loop starts at `i = 50` - so the first 50 wont be pushed into `artists` array

add

```
for (var j = 0; j < 50 && artists.length < total; j++) {
    artists.push(response.items[j].track.album.artists[0].name);
}
```

before the while loop - like so

```
var artists = [];
loginButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    login(function(accessToken) {
        var i = 0;
        getUserData(accessToken, i)
        .then(function(response) {
            var total = response.total;
            // added code to store the first 50 artists
            for (var j = 0; j < 50 && artists.length < total; j++) {
                artists.push(response.items[j].track.album.artists[0].name);
            }
            // end added code
            while (i < total) {
                i += 50;
                getUserData(accessToken, i)
                .then(function(response) {
                    total = response.total;
                    alert(total); //testing
                    loginButton.style.display = 'none';

                    for (var j = 0; j < 50 && artists.length < total; j++) {
                        artists.push(response.items[j].track.album.artists[0].name);
                    }
                    alert(artists[7] + artists.length); //testing
                    alert(artists[artists.length - 1]); //testing
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The only issue with this is that the order of artists could conceivably be "wrong", in that one of the asynchronous getUserData could take longer than the next one (network issues are unpredictable)

You can rewrite your code to use `Array#map`, `Array#concat` and `$.when` - and preserve the order of data by doing so

> I'm assuming `response.total` is the total number of tracks, regardless of the offset and limit as this is implied by your code

```
loginButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    login(function(accessToken) {
        loginButton.style.display = 'none';
        var arr = [getUserData(accessToken, i)];
        arr[0]
        .then(function(response) {
            for (var i = 50; i < response.total; i += 50) {
                arr.push(getUserData(accessToken, i));
            }
            $.when.apply($, arr)
            .then(function() {
                var artists = [].concat.apply([], [].map.call(arguments, function(response) {
                    return response.items.map(function(item) {
                        return item.track.album.artists[0].name;
                    });
                }));
                // artists array is filled, now do what you need
            });
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            // handle errors here
        });
    });
});
```

As above but using native `Promise.all`

```
loginButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    login(function(accessToken) {
        loginButton.style.display = 'none';
        var arr = [getUserData(accessToken, i)];
        arr[0]
        .then(function(response) {
            for (var i = 50; i < response.total; i += 50) {
                arr.push(getUserData(accessToken, i));
            }
            Promise.all(arr).then(function(chunks) {
                var artists = [].concat.apply([], chunks.map(function(response) {
                    return response.items.map(function(item) {
                        return item.track.album.artists[0].name;
                    });
                }));
                // artists array is filled, now do what you need
            });
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            // handle errors here
        });
    });
});
```